# How come Java's TreeSet has no get() method?

Tags: java, collections, treeset

What if I want to retrieve and update objects that stored in a TreeSet?

The reason I'm asking, is that I want to be able to maintain some data stracture that will store Students.
I want it to be sorted (by grades - which is an instance variable of Student), and - it needs to be kept sorted even after I update one (or more) grade(s) as well.

So, after briefly looking over Java's collections, I decided to go with TreeSet and set a comparator that compares two students by their grades.
problem is, I just found out that TreeSet has no get() method!

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What would you expect a `get()` method on a `Set` to do?

- Sets are not indexed, so a `get(int index)` makes no sense. (Use a `List` if you want to get elements by index).
- `get(Object obj)` would also not make sense, because you'd have the object that you're trying to get already.
- There is already a `contains()` method to check if a `Set` contains an object.
- You can iterate over a `Set` if you want to do something with all elements in the set.

Comment: Just what I wanted to write: +1. Except for the indexed case: instead of "makes no sense" I would write "use a `List`"

Comment: Or use a `Map` to store the objects based on some key.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
So what options do I have here?

Comment: @so.very.tired That depends on what you want to do. What do you want to do, that you think you'd need a `get()` method for?

Comment: @Jesper I want to update Students average so that the collection will remain sorted after the update.

Comment: @so.very.tired If you're updating one of the fields that the comparator uses (the grade field of your `Student` object), then you'll have to (1) remove the `Student` from the `Set`, (2) update the variable and (3) put the `Student` back in the `Set`. Modifying the value that `Set` depends on to determine the order while it is in the `Set` will cause trouble.

Comment: I don't agree with the second. get(Object obj) is useful if the obj's compare method just compare the content, not the reference. So what if I want to get the reference of an element in Set?

Comment: I agree that a `get()` makes sense in a `SortedSet`

Comment: personal situation: I want a a sorted list with `TreeSet.floor` (and similar) methods defined on it. But still, many algorithms using it need index-get accessor. That's a good usage example of a TreeSet with get(index), no?

Comment: Your answer implies items in TreeSet are not nested. If I have            `TreeSet<TreeMap<String, Integer>> marketStocks = new TreeSet<>();` then it makes perfect sense. In this scenario we wish to avoid duplicate key mappings and use a set.

Comment: but what if I have a treeset, it is sorted, but it does not have get() either.....

Comment: So, if a `get(i)` doesn't make sense on a `SortedSet`, why are `first()` and `last()` provided?

Comment: @Yuri I didn't say `get(index)` doesn't make sense on a `SortedSet`. (It doesn't on a `Set` because a set is not an ordered collection). Since a `SortedSet` *is* an ordered collection, `first()` and `last()` do make sense. Why the designers of `java.util.SortedSet` didn't provide a `get(index)` method is a mistery.

Comment: I see, but because the question explicitly mentions a TreeSet, which implements a SortedSet, I thought that part seems to be a bit "overlooked" in the answer. Hence the explicit question. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Not true. It does make sense, since the comparable might be resolving to return an object given another object. you might want to get the object in the set to update a value such as a date, rather now, you might have to remove and then add, which is a more costly operation, not to mention that all other fields in the new instance also now has to be set, albeit you could update the removed instance and then put it back in. The used to get object might not in some cases have to be the same as the one in the set.

Comment: what if you have a treeset of nodes? then youd want to do this. maybe answer the question instead...

Answer (score 15):

You can retrieve the elements from the treeset by using an Iterator. You can try something like this:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = treeSet.iterator();

Integer current = 0;
while(it.hasNext() ) {
current = it.next();

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I do have a case where I use a two TreeSets (because they are faster in searches). One of these trees is huge, and the objects in the trees are different, so I create a mock object (of Type 2, second tree) that has the fields used to sort, using data from an object from the small tree and check if there is a counterpart on the second. Now I need to check a value from the object found in the second tree to add value on a report.

Using an iterator, instead of a binary search to retrieve the object I need, defeats the purpose of using a binary tree. The second tree is 5GB plus, finding matchings with data in the first tree (200MB). I need a search strategy that makes sense for this huge amount of data, therefore I chose a Binary Search tree. Entries are unique.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you will not want to retrieve an element in a set when you already have it. You might to remove your element from a set, or know if it belongs to a set, thats all. Know want you want to do is to index your students by grade, so the index is the grade, not the object itself. Map is the solution.

If I were you, I would use the following structure which retrieves all students with the 
same grade quickly (they are sorted by grades too) :

```
private SortedMap<Integer,Set<Student>> _studentsByGrade = new TreeMap<Integer,Set<Student>>();

public void updateStudent(Student student, int oldGrade, int newGrade)
{
  getOrCreateContainer(oldGrade).remove(student);
  getOrCreateContainer(newGrade).add(student);
  student.setGrade(newGrade);
}

public Set<Student> getOrCreateContainer(int grade)
{
  Set<Student> set = _studentsByGrade.get(grade);
  if(set==null)
  {
    set = new HashSet<Student>();
    _studentsByGrade.put(grade, set);
  }
  return set;
}
```

Don't forget to overload the equals and hashcode in your Student class to make it work correctly.

You might also want to check the cqengine library if you want to perform java indexations easily and fast, but the solution presented above is just ok for your usage.

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed no method get by reference or get by index. However, there is a simple way to build the get by reference method.
This can be achieved using the method `boolean contains(E input)` and `E ceiling(E input)`. In fact, according to the Javadoc of the ceiling method :

> Returns the least element in this set greater than or equal to
> the given element, or {@code null} if there is no such element.

So if we know beforehand that the element is in the set, then a call to ceiling is guaranteed to return the element that is equal to the input.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ExtendedTreeSet<E> extends TreeSet<E> {

  public ExtendedTreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    super(comparator);
  }

  public E get(E input) {
    return this.contains(input) ? this.ceiling(input) : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `TreeSet` is **sorted upon insertion**. If you order by students' grades and modify them *after* being added, the items are no longer sorted (same order as before).

The `TreeSet` also does not use `equals()` to determine if an element is already added, but uses the comparator instead (same order = same item). So if two students have the same grades, only one of them is added. From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo
>   (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this
>   method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.

Instead of using `TreeSet`, you can use a `HashSet` and **sort the students by grade whenever you need them** (create a new List containing the students, sort it and iterate over it).

Comment: So basically there's no actual way to do it dynamically.

Comment: At least not using the standard collections. As long as the ordering can be arbitrary (any Comparator or Comparable implementation), the collection would need a way to *observe* the contained objects for changes. This would require two interfaces, one for the observables (to be implemented by the objects) and one for the observer (listener interface with callback method, for the observer, which is the collection).

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the tree to retrieve its objects.
What about NavigableSet? there are methods for short distance navigation, as

```
E ceiling(E e) E floor(E e)
E higher(E e) E lower(E e)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer to the problem I found for myself but I thought there should be a `get(elem)` for sets,  but as you know, **there is not**.

Here you go:

```
set.subSet(elem,true,elem,true).floor(elem);
```

This returns you the first **object** that equals the one you're looking for.

**NOTE**:
    *elem* must be equals with the element you are looking for and you get the object you want **OR** assign a comparator to the set that matches them as *equals*.

---

I was surprised nobody came up with it before.

Thumbs up needed :D

Answer (score 1):

If it contains the exact object the floor will return the exact object which you are looking for.

```
if(set.contains(searchingObject)) {
   addonPartNumber =  p.floor(searchingObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use for-each to get all elements inside `TreeSet`.

```
TreeSet<String> words = new TreeSet<String>();
for(String w : words) {
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

You may perform iteration to copy the unique words from `TreeSet` into Lists, which gives you the privilege to use `get();`

Hope, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to get an element by key (being the key and the value the same thing in this case) would be:

```
A get(A a)
{
    var res = tree.floor(a);
    if (a.compareTo(res) == 0)
    {
        return res;
    }
    return null;
}
```